# Using Xamarin Forms - how can I hook up a button click to a swipe gesture?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture, hamburger-menu

I have an app using a master detail page and a navigation page within it. On Android when you navigate to the account page via the burger menu the nav bar stays at the top of the screen as expected so you can navigate using it. On iOS the nav bar disappears, so I've created a custom bar with a burger menu icon. When someone clicks the icon on the custom nav bar I want the burger menu to swipe out from the left.

I've attached a gesture recogniser to the burger icon but I don't know what to put in the called method to make it perform the swipe action.

Nav bar on second page:

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding _isiPhone}" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#008334">
    <Image Source="burger.png" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Burger_Clicked"></TapGestureRecognizer>
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</StackLayout>
```

Event handler:

```
private void Burger_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

android view:

[image: android view]

android burger menu view:

[image: android burger menu]

iOS view (with custom nav bar):

[image: iOS view]

iOS burger menu:

[image: iOS burger menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "IsPresented" property on the MasterDetail page to True/False to make the side menu show / hide.
Please reconsider if a custom bar is really needed, as the standard control should be something the users are used to.

Also please note that it is recommended to use a content page for the Master page, and you can use a NavigationPage/TabPage/ContentPage as needed for the detail page.

Refer to the [official docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/) for more information

Comment: Sorry, the inner page is a content page not navigation page.

I don't know how to access the IsPresented property from the account page?

Comment: You can cast Application.Current.MainPage to a MasterDetailPage. So something like ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).IsPresented = true; should show the slide out drawer.
Of course, you should only use this approach if your MasterDetailPage will always be in the root of your app when this code is triggered. You might need to test for that or store the reference in a different way, whatever suits your project and is the cleanest and easiest solution in your app architecture.